# Late 90's novel about conflict around replicator machines

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

This book had a strange title, I think it was one of those made up all capital letters titles. Unfortunately I remember none of the plot! Only vaguely that the theme was around conflict about replicators were anyone can make almost any products and the law and regulation around it and economics.. I think. The author added a foreword around 2001 it mentioned Napster. Another one about ten year later I think that mentioned 3d printers...

I THINK that the author may have been involved with Software Engineering at a big tech company but may just be confused about it.

Pretty sure it was published between 1997 - 2000.

Help this driving me nuts and Google and Goodreads is no help because of the weird title.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Could you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: Could it be Cory Doctorow? He wrote several stories based on similar premises (see *Unauthorized Bread* (2019)), as far back as 2001 with *Down and Out in the Magic Kingdom*.

Comment: No not Cory Doctorow almost certain about it

Comment: Definitely before 2001 author definitely mentioned Napster in foreword that was added at that time. More dystopian cyberpunk feel than that of Cory's.

Comment: If it wasn't before 2001 I'd have wondered about Doctorow too - Makers (2009) would be another possibility.

Comment: "I think it was one of those made up all capital letters titles" - do you mean the title was an acronym, or is this a comment on the cover design/font?

Comment: Well it's certainly not what you're looking for, but a book about essentially the same subject is *[The Complete Venus Equilateral](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2674050-the-complete-venus-equilateral)* by George O. Smith. It featured 3D copiers, that is, you had to have an original; you could then make as many indistinguishable copies as you wanted, including of money or original artworks. You could even use your 3D copier to manufacture 3D copiers! But the short stories it collects were written in the 1940's.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit like Charles Stross's *[Rule 34](https://www.fabbaloo.com/2011/08/3d-printings-rule-34-html)*.

> Charles Stross’s latest science fiction novel, Rule 34, includes a whole lot of deep thinking on the implications of widespread 3D printing. We’ve discussed some of these issues before, but Stross’s novel proposes another more aggressive solution: forbidden shapes. In other words, 3D printers could be rigged to detect and prevent the production of certain objects deemed illegal. The printers may even report you for attempting such, too.

The plot dances between three main threads. Inspector Kavanaugh does some enforcement of illegal printing of 3D items (mentioned in the narrative 3D printing of weapons, and of realistic dolls of other people, the "Rule 34" of the title, including some underage), Anwar a former identity thief who now works for the Operation, a criminal organization, and The Toymaker, an enforcer for the Operation.

As a 2011 book, it would be a little bit late on your time table (the prior book, *Halting State*, about an MMO heist tied to real money, was released in 2007). One thing that might stick out to you if you read most or all of the book is that The Toymaker is a paranoid schizophrenic, convinced that he's always being watched by beings that want to skin him and wear his flesh, and near the end of the book, Kavanaugh muses that, with mass surveillance being what it is, paranoid schizophrenics aren't necessarily wrong that they're always being watched.

Comment: Also would explain why a simple Google search for the title wouldn't work too well...

Comment: Unfortunately not Stross or Doctorow... I think this book is quite obscure but had a very modern theme... published before 2001 Napster people! :)

Comment: I was thinking of Stross too, but "Singularity Sky" which had the cornucopia machines. At 2003 this is too late too though.